# Replacing GPS Tag values [Editing EXIF]

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg, exif

I am trying to remove a tag to be able to re-add it with a corrected value. The exif tag in question is: GPSImgDirection but it does not seem to save the new values(i'm guessing it's not removing/finding the tag)

What exactly am I doing wrong? I've been trying to follow the example file from apache (WriteExifMetadataExample.java).

P.S. I set constant values in the Rational value to simplify the example of code...

```
public static void setBearing(File f, Double bearing)
    throws IOException, ImageReadException, ImageWriteException{

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f.getParent()+ File.separator+"SUPERTMPDUMP12324231.jpg",false);
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);) {

        TiffOutputSet outputSet = null;

        final ImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()));
        final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
        if (null != jpegMetadata) {
            final TiffImageMetadata exif = jpegMetadata.getExif();

            if (null != exif) {
                outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();
            }
        }

        if (null == outputSet) {
            outputSet = new TiffOutputSet();
        }

        Rational r = new Rational(bearing);    
        final TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();

        exifDirectory.removeField(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION );
        exifDirectory.add(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION, new RationalNumber(454349, 10000));


        new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossless(f, os,
                outputSet);
        //Replace file with new meta data
        Files.move(Paths.get(f.getPath()+ File.separator+"SUPERTMPDUMP12324231.jpg"), Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, because it's in the "GPS" Directory I need to:

```
final TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateGPSDirectory();
```

instead of

```
final TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
```